# Is there any other way to change the color to the bootstrap nav links ? Using dark theme

Tags: html, css

When using the bootstrap framework and trying to change the nav-link colors on the dark theme , there is a very specific way of targeting and is the only way and I am curious if somebody figured out another way .

This is the only selector that worked

```
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .active > .nav-link
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, while using this framework, we're using it's own css so the selector needs to go according to the pre-defined one in the css. However, you can tweak it by "!important". For example:

```
.nav-link {
    color: #000 !important; 
}
```

Comment: I was looking for a non !important method as i am told it is not good . I am a beginner so i do not know a lot about these yet .

Comment: Oh, I see. Bootstrap is a good thing to start with :) Yes, the "!important" tweak is not advised, but helps at times. Regarding alternate selectors, I'm afraid since ".navbar-dark .navbar-nav .active > .nav-link" is already used in the CSS of bootstrap, to select the elements in class nav-links, we'll need to use the same selector. However, I'd suggest you to keep the question open, so that if there is any other solution, we'll both get to know it. Have a great day ahead.

Comment: Thank you for your input and for advice  . I'll leave this open